# need to open/close modal with array variable using javascript only

Tags: javascript, html

```css
.modal {
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 z-index:1;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 overflow: auto;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.close_btn{
 color: black;
 float:right;
 font-size:28px;
 font-weight:bold;
}

.close_btn:hover,
.close_btn:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>In Gravida</h2>
        <h2>In gravida</h2>
        <h3>Cras ac mauris</h3>
        <p class="p_light_box">nteger dictum hendrerit pharetra. Cras fermentum posuere egestas.</p>
        <button type="btn" id="Learn_Btn" class="Learn_Btn"><a>Learn More <span><img src="images/arrow-btn-blue.png" width="10%" height="10%"></span></a></button>
        <h3>Curabitur elementum</h3>
        <p class="p_light_box">Cras vel imperdiet mauris. Pellentesque libero mauris, interdum a felis et, condimentum mattis erat.</p>
        <a>Learn More</a>
        <h3>Awards and Recognitions</h3>
        <p class="p_light_box">Aliquam eget ligula mauris. Etiam viverra non turpis eu auctor. Nullam pretium est libero, et condimentum massa egestas id. </p>
        <a>Learn More</a>
        <h3>Morbi placerat </h3>
        <pclass="p_light_box"> Nam feugiat ultrices ligula eget faucibus. Mauris convallis ipsum est.</p>
        <a>Learn More</a>
        <h3>Suspendisse eu</h3>
        <p class="p_light_box">Duis pretium elementum dui, id feugiat neque facilisis vel.</p>
        <a>Learn More</a>
        <h3> Integer faucibus</h3>
        <p class="p_light_box"> Vivamus at rutrum est, eu pellentesque lacus. Curabitur imperdiet tortor sit amet enim ullamcorper, a aliquet odio rutrum.</p>
        <a>Learn More</a>
        <h2>Products</h2>
        Fitler by
        <select>
            <option>All</option>
            <option>Less Than $500</option>
            <option>From $500 to $1000</option>
            <option>From $1000 to $2000</option>
            <option>$2000 or more</option>
        </select>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Product Title 1 <br>
                Staring at $500 <br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>
                <a>Learn More</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                Product Title 2<br>
                Staring at 1900<br>
                Donec ornare magna sit amet erat molestie sollicitudin ac vitae lectus.</br>
                <a>Learn More</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                Product Title 3<br>
                Staring at $2730<br>
                Cras non metus sed odio tristique imperdiet.</br>
                <button id="product_3" class="Learn_Btn"><a>Learn More</a></button>
            </li>
            <li>
                Product Title 4<br>
                Staring at $731<br>
                Pellentesque mattis tellus ut molestie dapibus.</br>
                <button id="product_4" class="Learn_Btn"><a>Learn More</a></button>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var products ='';
   window.products = {
   1: {
    id : 1,
    order: 1,
    'title' : 'Product Title 1',
    'price' : 'Staring at $500',
    'desc' : 'Cras a ante eget dui dignissim molestie nec non lectus. Donec id sapien tristique, iaculis odio a, gravida ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent non lacus elit. Sed convallis erat sem, ac egestas ipsum tempor in. Sed consectetur ex at dolor ullamcorper vulputate. Ut tristique ipsum velit, eget pretium ipsum dictum vel. Aenean ut tempus elit, non facilisis odio. Vivamus hendrerit ipsum vel risus ultrices, ut ornare metus ornare. Quisque semper ante ac pellentesque vestibulum. Cras a massa turpis. Pellentesque congue leo velit, non porta dui euismod nec.<br> <br> Mauris sed enim risus. Quisque mollis justo quis commodo euismod. Nullam non massa in lorem cursus sagittis. Sed laoreet felis mauris, a eleifend sapien molestie eget. Duis at volutpat elit. Phasellus sit amet erat ut libero lobortis sollicitudin pellentesque ac lectus. Phasellus venenatis ultrices justo nec venenatis.<br><br>'
     +'<ul>'
       + '     <li>Non porta dui euismod nec</li>'
       + '     <li>Ut tristique ipsum velit</li>'
           + '     <li>Quisque mollis justo</li>'
     +'</ul>',
    'uri-stub'   : '/buy-mattress/iseries/iseries-hybrid/iseries-approval-super-pillow-top',
        'src'        : 'material/000010885.jpg'
   },
   2: {
    id : 2, 
    order: 2,
    'title' : 'Product Title 2',
    'price' : 'Staring at $1900',
    'desc' : 'Cras a ante eget dui dignissim molestie nec non lectus. Donec id sapien tristique, iaculis odio a, gravida ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent non lacus elit. Sed convallis erat sem, ac egestas ipsum tempor in. Sed consectetur ex at dolor ullamcorper vulputate. Ut tristique ipsum velit, eget pretium ipsum dictum vel. Aenean ut tempus elit, non facilisis odio. Vivamus hendrerit ipsum vel risus ultrices, ut ornare metus ornare. Quisque semper ante ac pellentesque vestibulum. Cras a massa turpis. Pellentesque congue leo velit, non porta dui euismod nec.<br> <br> Mauris sed enim risus. Quisque mollis justo quis commodo euismod. Nullam non massa in lorem cursus sagittis. Sed laoreet felis mauris, a eleifend sapien molestie eget. Duis at volutpat elit. Phasellus sit amet erat ut libero lobortis sollicitudin pellentesque ac lectus. Phasellus venenatis ultrices justo nec venenatis.',
    'uri-stub'   : '/buy-mattress/iseries/iseries-hybrid/iseries-approval-super-pillow-top',
        'src'        : 'material/ff_x20_008.JPG'
   },
   3: {
    id : 3,
    order: 3,
    'title' : 'Product Title 3',
    'price' : 'Staring at $2730',
    'desc' : 'Cras a ante eget dui dignissim molestie nec non lectus. Donec id sapien tristique, iaculis odio a, gravida ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent non lacus elit. Sed convallis erat sem, ac egestas ipsum tempor in. Sed consectetur ex at dolor ullamcorper vulputate. Ut tristique ipsum velit, eget pretium ipsum dictum vel. Aenean ut tempus elit, non facilisis odio. Vivamus hendrerit ipsum vel risus ultrices, ut ornare metus ornare. Quisque semper ante ac pellentesque vestibulum. Cras a massa turpis. Pellentesque congue leo velit, non porta dui euismod nec.<br> <br> Mauris sed enim risus. Quisque mollis justo quis commodo euismod. Nullam non massa in lorem cursus sagittis. Sed laoreet felis mauris, a eleifend sapien molestie eget. Duis at volutpat elit. Phasellus sit amet erat ut libero lobortis sollicitudin pellentesque ac lectus. Phasellus venenatis ultrices justo nec venenatis.',
    'uri-stub'   : '/buy-mattress/iseries/iseries-hybrid/iseries-approval-super-pillow-top',
        'src'        : 'material/sample1.jpg'
   },
   4: {
    id : 4,
    order: 4,
    'title' : 'Product Title 4',
    'price' : 'Staring at $731',
    'desc' : 'Cras a ante eget dui dignissim molestie nec non lectus. Donec id sapien tristique, iaculis odio a, gravida ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent non lacus elit. Sed convallis erat sem, ac egestas ipsum tempor in. Sed consectetur ex at dolor ullamcorper vulputate. Ut tristique ipsum velit, eget pretium ipsum dictum vel. Aenean ut tempus elit, non facilisis odio. Vivamus hendrerit ipsum vel risus ultrices, ut ornare metus ornare. Quisque semper ante ac pellentesque vestibulum. Cras a massa turpis. Pellentesque congue leo velit, non porta dui euismod nec.<br> <br> Mauris sed enim risus. Quisque mollis justo quis commodo euismod. Nullam non massa in lorem cursus sagittis. Sed laoreet felis mauris, a eleifend sapien molestie eget. Duis at volutpat elit. Phasellus sit amet erat ut libero lobortis sollicitudin pellentesque ac lectus. Phasellus venenatis ultrices justo nec venenatis.',
    'uri-stub'   : '/buy-mattress/iseries/iseries-hybrid/iseries-approval-super-pillow-top',
        'src'        : 'images/candy_b.jpg'
   }
   }
   
   /*Get Modal*/
   var modal = document.getElementById("Modal_1");
   
   var btn = document.getElementById("product_3");
   
   //var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close_btn");
   
   btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
   }
   
   //span.onclick = function(){
    //modal.style.display = "none";
   //}
   </script>
```

I get modal is null; I have no idea how to get the variable data by id and place inside a modal. I assume I need to create a modal class and put a div like so...

```
 <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="product_3">Learn More about Product 3</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="Modal_1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close_btn">x</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I couldn't get my modal to open at all thus couldn't close it either I haven't worked with javascript like this

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jvpink200/h1LLjtfr/4/#&togetherjs=9zvezsQCbE